# Can Presto server connect to Snowflake directly or only via starburst?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, presto, starburst

I am trying to find a snowflake connector for Presto but unable to find any in Presto documentation.All searches are showing connection via starburst only.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Starburst only. But there is ongoing PR.
https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/2551

Comment: Might be worth adding that the connector in the PR and the one Starburst's offers are not  equivalent. In particular, Starburst's is a parallel, higher performance connector.